# Route shadowsocks traffic through openvpn in server side

Tags: networking, routing, openvpn, linux-networking

So I want to implement a thing like this :

1. A client connect to my shadowsocks server.
2. Shadowsocks server send request to remote server ( a server that client trying to connect to that ) through openvpn
3. Retrieve result ( response ) from openvpn and send it back to client by shadowsocks.

How can I implement that in a ubuntu18.04 server ?